# why doesnt Double.infinite return true for infinite fractions?

Tags: java, double

```
Double.isInfinite(1.0 / 0.0);
```

returns true.

```
Double.isInfinite(1.0 / 3.0);
```

but this doesnt, and to my understanding this would be an infinite number as this returns 0.33333_ to infinity.

why?

Comment: An infinite number is a number that is not finite. 1/3 is finite because it can be measured and given a value.

Comment: Also, what would you expect for [PI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Double.isInfinite` does not return true if the value is infinitely long; it returns true if the value is itself infinite (either positive or negative).

Also, 1.0/3.0 is infinitely long in base 10, but not in other bases, like base 3.

Comment: In addition, a floating point representation of a number is never irrational (ex: pi) there will be some upper level limit to precision. This is programming not math :)

Comment: Is there a way to check if a number is infinitely long ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis: What you you mean "infinitely long"?  Any precisely-computed fraction written in decimal format will end with an infinitely repeating non-zero string of digits unless the reduced-form denominator would be a power-of-two multiple of a power of five.

Comment: You can't check infinitely long, because there's no way for a float to distinguish between "one divided by three" and, say, "0.333...<a thousand 3's>4." Both would be represented by the same floating point value (which is very close to 1/3), so how is Java to know that one should be "infinitely long" and the other shouldn't?

Comment: interesting lol this is for the projectEuler problem(reciprocal fraction), I must be approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I haven't tried that problem, but off the top of my head, it sounds like you should be working with integers, not floats -- you want to be looking at digits, not the values they represent. I would suggest doing it on paper first: how do we know that 1/3 has infinitely many 3's? How do we know that 1/7 has infinitely many (142857)s? This is a long division problem at its core, not a floating point problem. Then, for each number, figure out what its recurring cycle is. Then for each one of those, figure out how many digits is in that cycle. Then figure out the longest of those.

Comment: @yshavit thanks! I wish I could deduce the steps to a problem off the top of my head like that :(

Comment: Don't thank me yet, we're not sure if that's actually the right way to do it. ;) Hopefully it'll help set you in the right direction, though. Good luck, I'm sure you'll figure out! Just remember, don't jump to coding too quickly. The first step is always to think how you'd do it without a computer, and only then do you try to get a computer to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The type `double` can only represent certain fractions.  The expression 1.0/3.0 yields doesn't yield the fraction "one third", but rather selects the closest fraction which `double` is capable of representing.  Among the roughly 18,000,000,000,000,000,000 fractions `double` can represent, the one closest to one third is 6004799503160661/18014398509481984, and so the expression `1.0/3.0` yields that precise value.  While the actual fraction "one third" would be infinitely long when expressed in decimal or binary format, the closest `double` is not "infinite" in any sense of the word; even writing it out in decimal format would only require 54 digits to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

There are two values defined as `infinity` in [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) (+/- infinity). Since double is floating point, it follows those rules. However, if you were to use an arbitrary precision type (like [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)) you might be able to implement such a test - for example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal ONE = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal THREE = new BigDecimal("3");
    BigDecimal THIRD = ONE.divide(THREE);
    System.out.println(THIRD);
}
```

Will throw an exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.